# How to implement "DistBelief" architecture in Distributed Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, distributed

The current architecture of Distributed Tensorflow is based on the "Parameter-Server-like" framework. Using `tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter())`, all tensor "Variables" are placed on the "parameter server" ("PS"), and other tensor ops are assigned to "workers". From what I understand, there would be much communication overhead between the "worker" and "PS". The reason is each worker does not have no local replicas of those "Variables" stored in "PS", which actually introduces much more communications during training, to retrieve variables from "PS", compute the intermediate results and send them back to "PS" to update those tensor "Variables"...

Now if we don't follow the rule, instead, we adopt the "DistBelief" architecture: All shared parameters (like neural network weights) are still placed on "PS", but each worker now has the replicas of the shared tensor "Variables" which are stored in "PS". The benefit is during training each worker does not have to communicate with "PS", but just uses its local replicas to compute gradients, and the communication between "worker" and "PS" only happens when the shared parameters (neural network weights) are updated in "PS". In distributed Tensorflow, is there a way doing it?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that in addition to global variables, handled by chief worker, non-chief workers have their own sets of local variables which need to be initialized on worker restart.

Take a look at this [example](https://github.com/abenmao/tensorflow/blob/86498c37a589fe38a9464b15b2f39b1576b8cbec/tensorflow/contrib/opt/python/training/model_average_optimizer.py) by [abenmao](https://github.com/abenmao/). You create session.run hook which either initializes local variables or global variables. You then create MonitoredTraining session with the correct hook, depending on whether the worker is chief or not.

````
  ma_hook = ma.make_ma_run_hook()
  # And also, create the hook which handles initialization and queues.
  ma_replicas_hook = ma.make_session_run_hook(is_chief)
  ```
  In the training program, every worker will run the train_op as if not
  model_average or synchronized. Note that if you want to run other ops like
  test op, you should use common session instead of monitoredSession:
  ```python
  with training.MonitoredTrainingSession(
      master=workers[worker_id].target, is_chief=is_chief,
      hooks=[ma_replicas_hook, ma_hook]) as mon_sess:
    while not mon_sess.should_stop():
      mon_sess.run(training_op)
  ...

  def make_session_run_hook(self, is_chief, num_tokens=0):
    """Creates a hook to handle ReplicasHook ops such as initialization."""
    if self._ma_run_hook is False:
      raise ValueError("make_session_run_hook Should be "
                       "called after make_ma_run_hook.")

    if is_chief:
      return self._ReplicasHook(self.chief_init_op,
                                self.ready_for_local_init_op,
                                self.get_chief_queue_runner(),
                                self.get_init_tokens_op(num_tokens))

    return self._ReplicasHook(self.local_step_init_op,
                              self.ready_for_local_init_op, None, None)
````

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Seems the answer solved my other issue ;) But the example link is great - `model_average_device_setter()` could place global model variables on PS, while each worker also has replicas. It would be really nice to be included in the future release, since current tf only supports `tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter())`, where all tensor "Variables" are placed on the PS, and each worker doesn't have local replicas of them, which introduces much communication cost as I stated above.